# Including module in haskell during ghcjs in compile time

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

I want to compile a haskell code to javascript and have the following error during compiling.

```
> ghcjs Main.hs 

Main.hs:2:8:
    Could not find module ‘Reflex.Dom’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Main.hs:4:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Matrix’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Ratio (from base-4.8.0.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I am not using stack, and I wonder how should I provide with the libraries during compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cabal to manage your project, write dependency in build-dep session. Then install your project.

Comment: can you be please more specific. I am a noob right now, so any help better would be appreciated !